# AngularJS replace using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have to replace HTML (matched words) of a page on load. I only need to replace the words matched within `<div>` and `<p>` tags though. I am using angularJS for this.

My function so far -

```
var elementsList = e.find('p');

var regex = ('[^<>\\n]*?\\b(Cat|Dog|Fish)\\b[^<>\\n]*?', 'gi');                 

angular.forEach(elementsList, function(_element){
    var eHtml = $(_element).html();
    e.html(eHtml .replace(regex, function(fullMatch, match){
    if(angular.isString(match))
    {
         return 'TEST' + match;
    }
    }));
    $compile($(_element).html())($scope);
  });                                                                 

$compile(e.contents())($scope);
```

But this isn't updating the html of the page correctly. It replaces the whole sentence instead of just replacing the matched word.

So for example the html is

```
<p>I am a dog.</p>
<p>I am a cat.</p>
<p>I am not a dog but a cat.</p>
```

I want the result to be

```
<p>I am a TESTdog.</p>
<p>I am a TESTcat.</p>
<p>I am not a TESTdog but a TESTcat.</p>
```

Comment: `'[^<>\\n]*?\\b(Cat|Dog|Fish) + ')\\b[^<>\\n]*?'` three single quotes.

Comment: Sorry, updated. Had copied it directly from my JS file.

Comment: still it has three quotes. Check the coloring, it's red.

Comment: Ah, didn't update before. Updated now.

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp('[^<>\\n]*?\\b(Cat|Dog|Fish)\\b[^<>\\n]*?', 'gi'); `

Comment: a simple example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: @NomadTraveler can you provide simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) with sample? also what you mean: _It replaces the whole sentence instead of just replacing the matched word._?

Comment: also what is `e` in your sample, why you before find inside it `p` tag and then set `e.html` on each loop iteration

Comment: can you provide complex sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you confused element with full html and element for concrete `<p>` tag.

here

```
angular.forEach(elementsList, function(_element){
```

you go to `elementList` that contains `<p>` tag and `_element` refers to concrete `<p>` from this list, but next you get html from this element

```
var eHtml = $(_element).html();
```

replace it

```
eHtml.replace(regex, function(fullMatch, match){ ... })
```

and instert in main `e` element

```
e.html(eHtml.replace(...))
```

so instead replace html for concrete tag, you replace full html, and do this on each loop iteration.

So possibly you should use `$(_element)` instead just `e`

```
$(_element).html(eHtml.replace(...))
```

**UPDATE** also seems you regex can be reduced to

```
/\b(Cat|Dog|Fish)\b/gi
```

and used like

```
var regex = /\b(Cat|Dog|Fish)\b/gi;
$(_element).html(eHtml.replace(regex, "Test$1"));
```